# Abortar a execução de um SQL de longa duração

Tags: delphi, firedac

Tenho um SQL bem demorado (mais de 10 minutos) para retornar os dados.
Porém, ele é executado numa *Thread* e portanto a *MainThread* continua sendo executada normalmente. Enquanto o SQL está sendo executado, o usuário pode encerrar o sistema, e aí mora o problema.
Porque o sistema até fecha, porém o processo continua sendo executado no gerenciador de tarefas até o SQL retornar os dados solicitados.

Tem como abortar a execução do SQL imediatamente?

Dados:

- Delphi XE 7
- FireDAC
- FireBird
- Não adianta mudar o SQL para ficar mais rápido, é lento mesmo e não
  tem como fugir disso.

Comment: MyThread.Terminate; em tese terminaria, mas eu duvido que termine porque o processo esta 'preso' no banco.

Comment: Exatamente, o problema não está em encerrar a Thread, mas sim no fato de estar preso no banco.

Comment: Não vejo como. A não ser mudando a lógica. Tipo selecionando aos poucos. Então você, não deixa o programa fechar quando estiver no banco, sabendo que ele voltará em breve e então decide se continua ou não.

Comment: Note que assim como sua aplicação, o SQL Server também tem seu controle de processos e threads. Acredito fortemente que haja `stored procedure` que você possa usar no banco pra matar um processo por lá. O negócio é descobrir o id de processo da consulta no banco...

Comment: Exatamente. Pensei no Kill( id ), mas...

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar o banco de dados: **Firebird**

Comment: Piorou. Não tem kill no Firebird. Ele não trata essa questão por usuário matou um, mata todos.

Comment: Crie um método (ex: `FinalizarProcesso`) na classe da sua thread com o SQL. Nele, chame `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess, 0);`. Daí, da thread principal você chama esse método da thread com o SQL, depois chame o `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess, 0);` na própria thread principal. Aliás, eu acho que na thread principal nem tem necessidade, basta finalizar normalmente com o `Application.Terminate`.

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma sugestão:
Crie uma estrutura de tabela no seu banco de dados ou crie uma pasta para receber arquivos texto com conteudos de XML/Json.

Após criar a estrutura a cima, invés de ser feita uma thread e realizar a consulta SQL neste thread, faça o seguinte:

Crie um WebService ou uma DLL para realizar o chamado do método com o SQL, neste método, gere um ID e retorne para o seu chamador. Ainda dentro do seu WS/COM execute a query e após a execução, crie um XML/JSON com os dados e salve em um banco de dados ou na pasta informando o ID informado anteriormente.
Exemplo:
89.txt(Caso salvar na pasta).

Agora é possível criar uma thread que fica consultando a pasta/BD de tempos em tempos para verificar se aquele ID já foi gerado e assim apresentar o resultado em sua aplicação.

Caso sua aplicação tenha sido encerrada, não terá nenhum processamento pendente no gerenciamento de processos.

Espero que a ideia tenha ficado clara.